# How to call a function when the Compass Button of a mapView is pressed

Tags: swift, mapkit

I have developed an app showing a map view with a compass button. The natural function when pressing this compass button is that the map is being oriented to north. 
Now I want to call a function when pressing this compass button.

A view of the app with a map can be found there (compass button is visible in the upper right corner)

http://aceingolf.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/0.jpg

The code below is working fine. It is just shown to give a complete view.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let compassButton = MKCompassButton(mapView: mapView)   
compassButton.compassVisibility = .visible       
mapView.addSubview(compassButton)
```

I am looking for a way to create an action when the user presses the compass button on the map view.

Comment: `MKCompassButton` is a subclass of `UIView`. Just add an `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: You should think twice about changing the function of established UI elements. Users’ expectations have been set by previous experience and you should have a very good reason for going against that. Are you sure that a separate control wouldn’t be a better solution?

Comment: @ Magnas: fully shared. In my case I am using a zoomed map in the same view. I want to synchronize the orientation of both maps. That is the reason I need to put some additional.code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `MKCompassButton` inherits from `UIView`, So you can just add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `compassButton` with an action like following:

```
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleCompassTap))
    compassButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)


    @objc func handleCompassTap() {
    // Implement your feature when the compass button tapped.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take emrepuns code

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleCompassTap))
compassButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)


@objc func handleCompassTap() {
// Implement your feature when the compass button tapped.
}
```

and add this line

```
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
```

or

```
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
```